# JDBC Date Filtering with Milliseconds with '>=' and '<' does not works on Microsoft SQL when using TIMESTAMP literal type

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, timestamp

This question is about the date filtering using '>=' and '<' on the date format, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS with specifically, ended with 0 and 9. This problem only happen on SQL Server as I had tested the JDBC script on OracleSQL and PostgreSQL.

I had a script where I want to get the date between 000 to 001 milliseconds but it does not return the date expected

[image]

When I do the script without timestamp literal type, the date is shown

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? or any solution that had been provided do provide the link,

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text

Comment: If you read the documentation, using a string will be implicitly converted to a `datetime` which only has a resolution of 3ms in SQL server. If instead you cast your string to a `datetime2` which has 1ms resolution (higher actually) you should get the results you want .

Comment: And please only tag the rbdms you require your answer in

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp literal type? That's not SQL server syntax.

Comment: @DaleK that's some weird ODBC syntax i think

Comment: When you asked your question, you were told *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Comment: Why *are* you using ODBC literals, and not just a string literal?

Comment: Is allocation_date a varchar field? That might be the problem. When you use ts literal, the datatype of the field becomes datetime, which doesn't support .001 ms resolution as above persons mentioned. While when you filter by a string, and the datatype of the Allocation_date is varchar, no conversion occurs and the query "works".

Comment: *"on the date format, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS with specifically"* date and time data types don't have a format, so this doesn't make sense either. Your image, which you;ve still not addressed, doesn't show that format either.

Comment: I'm actually using jdbc for cross platform database, and if I remember correctly, the { ts dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} is the date literal type to define the date time as timestamp.. I paste them to the Microsoft sql managment studio for better visual, that's my intention..

Comment: Because you appear to refuse to address the images, a reminder: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)